# can not install vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to install extensions in VSCode, but it does not work.

1. When using the extensions manager, after clicking the "install" button and waiting a long time, nothing happens.
2. When using command line, it just ends without any change.

I have tried to download the latest version of VSCode, uninstalled the old one and installed latest version.

I also tried to switch to another network, but still cannot install any extension.

There is no error message. Can anybody help to figure out how to install extensions?

*Install attempt using extensions manager:*

[image: install by extensions manager]

*Install attempt using command line:*

[image: install by command line]

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to provide my environment.
System: Windows 10 enterprise x64

Comment: Maybe start with "netstat 1" from command prompt while installing, so see if there is any internet activity.  Have you looked in the event log to see if there are any messages?

Comment: I tried "netstat 1", and no connection build. What can I do next?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be your answer, but I had the same issue.

All of a sudden I was unable to install any extensions. Using the log at

`OUTPUT` >> `LOG (SHARED)`

I was able to see

```
[2022-08-23 16:32:44.127] [sharedprocess] [info] Starting worker process with pid 16428 (type: fileWatcher, window: 1).
[2022-08-23 16:32:44.371] [sharedprocess] [info] WSL is not installed, so could not detect WSL profiles
[2022-08-23 16:32:51.725] [sharedprocess] [info] Getting Manifest... streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
[2022-08-23 16:32:51.730] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
[2022-08-23 16:32:51.850] [sharedprocess] [info] Downloaded extension: streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs\streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker-2.6.0
```

All the other posts on this topic are about SSL/CA checking, DNS issues, corporate proxy, etc. This isn't that, this is clearly downloading file but would just hang there and never extract.

I went to `C:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions` and found a `.obsolete` file. Removed it and extension installing immediately started working again.

Years too late, but maybe it helps the next person!

Answer (score -3):

Try to delete whatever has been downloaded to the actual extensions folder, and download again.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm completely new here